# Counter Strike 1.6 crashes when patching with UCP

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike

I've installed Counter Strike 1.6 and when I open it; it works just fine. However when I attempt to patch it with **UCP** it shows this:

```
Problem signature:   
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH   
Application Name:   ucp.exe   
Application Version:    8.5.0.0   
Application Timestamp:  55ebd911   
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_e41d   
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0   
Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000   
Exception Code: c0000005   
Exception Offset:   00160b7c   
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1   
Locale ID:  1033   
Additional Information 1:   e41d   
Additional Information 2:   e41d74f370ce617732729af7bb738d1d   
Additional Information 3:   9789 
Additional Information 4:   97896cd646cba0f22c06eb01e344bc7f
```

I've tried running it in Compatibility Mode for Windows XP.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit with Intel Core 2 Quad  (4 CPUS) 2.4 Ghz and 4 GB Ram.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this it may help:

Go to System and click "Remote Settings". The system properties should appear. Click the "Advanced" tab, TAB not button. and then click on the Settings button for Performance.

The Performance Options will appear, navigate to the "Data Execution Prevention" tab and select *Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select:*. Click the "Add..." button and add the Half Life Launcher (hl).

Comment: I've tried this but same error comes